# How do I make whole area clickable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uilabel

So I have a UIbutton that I created and made the image a specific image. That image has white space that i'm adding UILabel along with another image. All of those 2 new things inside of the white space in the UIButton image. Is there anyway to make them all clickable? Or Since they're inside of the UIButton, if I just make the UIButton clickable they will be as well? I just don't want it to be a case where if user clicks the label or other image, it doesn't overlap the UIButton and not register the click if that makes any sense

Comment: Can not understand your question?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: 2 options are to make a clear button that overlays the area you want to be clickable, or add a tap gesture recognizer on a view that other overlays, or contains your views that you want to be tappable.

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on UX - User Experience. App users don't want to guess what they can/can't do.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting the image an a button, just use a `UIImageView` and add a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.  Then, in your viewController, use something like `let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("handleTap:"))` to access and use your Gesture Recognizer.